# Java HTTP request transformers

Tags: java, api

I'm considering adapting a legacy API to a newer API by transforming incoming HTTP requests. I'm using Spring and Jersey. Right now, the way I am transforming incoming HTTP requests is by introducing a Servlet filter which wraps the incoming `HttpServletRequest` in an adapter object which transforms request components (headers, post body, query, etc.) to the newer request model.

My question is if there are other tools to do this kind of thing. I know of Mule ESB and Spring Integration, which have transformers / converters to do this kind of thing. I feel these are a little heavyweight for my purpose, however.

Here's an example of an old request, and the new request I want it mapped to.

Old:

```
GET /resource?id=abc&auth=xyz&params=<encoded-params>
```

New:

```
GET /resource/id?<unencoded-params>
Authorization: xyz
```

Thanks!

Comment: in order to make suggestions, it would help to understand what the "newer request model" is. What do you need to transform HttpServletRequests into?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to clarify here is Mule is an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus). But what you are infact looking for is RESTful webservices. There is JSR311 for all the RESTful implementations.

Here are some of them (other than [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)):

- [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)
- [XFire](http://xfire.codehaus.org/)
- [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)
- [Resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)
- [Wink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wink)

Comment: I'm asking what tools may exist that are comparable to the transformer / converter components of Mule / Spring Integration. Neither Jersey or Servlets provide a clean and sophisticated way of transforming HTTP requests. If any of the JSR311 implementations you listed provide more sophisticated ways to do so, that'd be great.

Comment: I would recommend to use CXF. It can be integrated very well with http://camel.apache.org